# De-merge document based on a field's array data

Tags: mongodb

I have my MongoDb documents like this:

```
{
  ... OTHER FIELDS ...
  "Name": "3m india ltd.",
  "BSECode": "523395",
  "NSECode": "3MINDIA",
  "News": {
    "Bites": [
      {
        "href": "https://www.thehindubusinessline.com/companies/3m-india-develops-cleaning-solution-covid-relevant-signage-for-global-application/article34462888.ece",
        "headline": "3M India develops cleaning solution, Covid-relevant signage for global application",
        "timestamp": "1 day ago",
        "publisher": "The Hindu Businessline"
      },
      {
        "href": "https://www.business-standard.com/article/news-cm/apar-industries-ltd-leads-losers-in-a-group-121042701094_1.html",
        "headline": "Apar Industries Ltd leads losers in ‘A’ group",
        "timestamp": "6 days ago",
        "publisher": "Business Standard"
      }
    ]
  }
  ... OTHER FIELDS ...
}
```

I need to break each of these documents wrt `News.Bites` array field data like the following example:

```
{
  "Name": "3m india ltd.",
  "BSECode": "523395",
  "NSECode": "3MINDIA",
  "News": {
    "href": "https://www.thehindubusinessline.com/companies/3m-india-develops-cleaning-solution-covid-relevant-signage-for-global-application/article34462888.ece",
    "headline": "3M India develops cleaning solution, Covid-relevant signage for global application",
    "timestamp": "1 day ago",
    "publisher": "The Hindu Businessline"
  }
},
{
  "Name": "3m india ltd.",
  "BSECode": "523395",
  "NSECode": "3MINDIA",
  "News": {
    "href": "https://www.business-standard.com/article/news-cm/apar-industries-ltd-leads-losers-in-a-group-121042701094_1.html",
    "headline": "Apar Industries Ltd leads losers in ‘A’ group",
    "timestamp": "6 days ago",
    "publisher": "Business Standard"
  }
}
```

This is the projection query I have come up with yet:

```
coll.find({
  'News': {
    '$exists': true
  }
}, {
  '_id': 0, 
  'News.Bites': 1, 
  'NSECode': 1, 
  'BSECode': 1, 
  'Name': 1
});
```

Can anyone please help with this?

Comment: You can use `$unwind` stage of aggregation query to transform each element of the array field to individual documents.

Comment: @prasad_ can you plz share the query sample?

Comment: You can find it MongoDB manual - here is the link to it: [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/). See the examples section for usage.